ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Notification"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a route named 'Notification'?
I am trying to make a top navigation bar in index.tsx so that when i click on the notification icon it will leads me to notification page.
@/app/_layout.tsx:
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/ui/useColorScheme';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    'Jost-Light': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-Light.ttf'),
    'Jost-Regular': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-Regular.ttf'),
    'Jost-Medium': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-Medium.ttf'),
    'Jost-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-Bold.ttf'),
    'Jost-SemiBold': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'Jost-ExtraBold': require('../assets/fonts/static/Jost-ExtraBold.ttf'),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="top/notification" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


@/app/(tabs)/index.tsx:
import { Image, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { HelloWave } from '@/components/HelloWave';
import ParallaxScrollView from '@/components/ParallaxScrollView';
import { ThemedText } from '@/components/ThemedText';
import { ThemedView } from '@/components/ThemedView';
import { TopBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TopBarIcon';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { HomeScreenNavigationProp } from '@/types'; 


const TopTabNavigator = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<HomeScreenNavigationProp>();

  return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notification')}>
      <TopBarIcon iconName="notifications" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
  );
}

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <>
  
    <TopTabNavigator/>

    <ParallaxScrollView
      headerBackgroundColor={{ light: '#A1CEDC', dark: '#1D3D47' }}
      headerImage={
        <Image
          source={require('@/assets/images/partial-react-logo.png')}
          style={styles.reactLogo}
        />
      }>
      <ThemedView style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <ThemedText type="regular">Welcome!</ThemedText>
        <HelloWave />
      </ThemedView>
      <ThemedView style={styles.stepContainer}>
        <ThemedText type="bold">Step 1: Try it</ThemedText>
        <ThemedText>
          Edit <ThemedText type="semiBold">app/(tabs)/index.tsx</ThemedText> to see changes.
          Press{' '}
          <ThemedText type="semiBold">
            {Platform.select({ ios: 'cmd + d', android: 'cmd + m' })}
          </ThemedText>{' '}
          to open developer tools.
        </ThemedText>
      </ThemedView>
      <ThemedView style={styles.stepContainer}>
        <ThemedText type="semiBold">Step 2: Explore</ThemedText>
        <ThemedText>
          Tap the Explore tab to learn more about what's included in this starter app.
        </ThemedText>
      </ThemedView>
      <ThemedView style={styles.stepContainer}>
        <ThemedText type="semiBold">Step 3: Get a fresh start</ThemedText>
        <ThemedText>
          When you're ready, run{' '}
          <ThemedText type="semiBold">npm run reset-project</ThemedText> to get a fresh{' '}
          <ThemedText type="semiBold">app</ThemedText> directory. This will move the current{' '}
          <ThemedText type="semiBold">app</ThemedText> to{' '}
          <ThemedText type="semiBold">app-example</ThemedText>.
        </ThemedText>
      </ThemedView>
    </ParallaxScrollView>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 8,
  },
  stepContainer: {
    gap: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  reactLogo: {
    height: 178,
    width: 290,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});


@/types.ts:
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Notification: undefined;
};

export type HomeScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Home'
>;

export type NotificationScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Notification'
>;

File structure:

I was trying to make the top bar in index.tsx to work such that when I click on the notification button, it will navigates me to the notification page.
But it keeps giving me this error when i have set up the routes.
